# A polynomial congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to find the solutions for the polynomial congruence equation using CRT 
$$\mbox{$x^3+4x+8$ is a multiple of modulo $15$.}$$
How can I find the solutions using CRT is there any easy method to find the roots of the equations?

Answer (score 1):

We have that 
$$x^3+4x+8\equiv 0 \pmod{15}\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}x^3+4x+8\equiv 0 \pmod{3}\\
x^3+4x+8\equiv 0 \pmod{5}\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}2x\equiv 1 \pmod{3}\\
x^3-x\equiv 2 \pmod{5}\end{cases}.$$ 
Note that for $x=0,1,2,3,4$ we obtain that 
$$x^3-x=x(x+1)(x-1)\equiv 0,0,1,4,0 \pmod{5}.$$
What may we conclude?

Comment: How 2x ≡1 (mod 3) and x^3−x≡2 (mod5) got from the previous step?

Comment: @aswanthpp  By Fermat's theorem $x^3\equiv x\pmod{3}$, and $x+4x+8\equiv 2x+2\pmod{3}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ \bmod 5 $ it's unsolvable, being equivalent to a quadratic with nonsquare discriminant, i.e. $\ x\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, x^4\equiv 1\,$ so $\,0 \equiv xf = (\color{#0a0}{2x+2)^2}-3\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#0a0}{n^2}\equiv \color{#c00}3\,$ contra $\,\{0,\pm1,\pm2\}^2\!\equiv \{\color{#c00}{0,\pm1}\}$